# Text that constantly changes between 2 colors

Tags: css, animation, text, colors

What are my options here? I'd like to have some text change from color A to color B constantly, not on hover.

I'm thinking CSS3 animations, or maybe Javascript. But JS seems a bit bulky for this.

I know I can use a .gif for this, but I'd prefer to actually have it be 'text' in case it is needed to be changed or dynamically generated, say, for a username.

Is CSS keyframes the best way to go? I'm a bit reluctant for the CSS animation method because of browser support. Does anyone have any better ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'd use CSS3 unless you're trying to maintain compatibility with "older" browsers. The javascript approach wouldn't be too onerous, but not as tidy as CSS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally recommend using CSS3 animations and gracefully degrading to non-animated text for unsupported browsers.

According to [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/css-animation), CSS 3 animations are supported by all major modern browsers: IE 10, Firefox 5+, Chrome, and Safari 4+ (for desktop browsers anyways). Mobile support looks pretty good as well. Of course, some of the browsers require prefixes (i.e. `-webkit-`).

If you require IE <= 9 support, you can always write the JavaScript and put it in a conditional comment. It's a bit redundant, but then again what isn't redundant when it comes to cross-browser compatible web design with leading technologies?

Also see the [MDN article on CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation).